# Is there a way to name interpolation placeholder from html component in i18n with Angular?

Tags: angular, localization, internationalization

In Angular, I'm using localization (i18n) to translate strings in my application. I have successfully used the $localize template literal in TypeScript files to translate strings with dynamic placeholders, like this:

`` this.createdBy = $localize`:@@CreatedBy:Created ${this.createdBy}:some_name:`; ``

However, I'm looking for a way to achieve a similar dynamic translation directly within an HTML template, similar to the above TypeScript example.

Is it possible to use $localize or another method in HTML to translate a string with dynamic placeholders like this?

I want the translated output to be stored in my extracted JSON file in a format similar to:

`"CreatedBy": "Created {$some_name}"`

not like:

`"CreatedBy": "Created {$INTERPOLATION}"`